# How can I update the live tile while the program is not running?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've been strugling a couple of days. I'm making a local weather app and I want the tile to show a image (weathericon), and text (name of the place + temperature).

In code you could do:

```
ShellTile firstTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
var newData = new StandardTileData()
{
    Title = "Placename, 50F",
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("background.png", UriKind.Relative),
};

// Update the default tile
firstTile.Update(newData);
```

But how do you do this while the app is not running, so I dont have to open the application to update the tile, but it does it by itself.

Comment: If your application is not running you won't be able to update the tile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set up a BackgroundAgent to do this.  Jeff Blankenburg has a good tutorial on doing this at http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/25/31-days-of-mango-day-25-background-agents/

A couple caveats:

- You can't control when it runs.
- Your images need to be hosted externally (e.g. not resources/content of the app). *Ku6opr says that images can be generated via code and placed into `/Shared/ShellContent` as an alternative.*
- Images need to be 173x173 pixels
- Images need to be less than 85K in size.

*edit: fixed pixel size.  was going from memory, and apparently those bits were fried*

Comment: > "Your images need to be hosted externally (e.g. not resources/content of the app)." Actually, you can generate images via code and place them into `/Shared/ShellContent/` folder to make `Tile` with image.

Comment: > "Images need to be exactly 179x179". Actually 173x173 is the right size of a tile

Comment: > "Images need to be less than 85K in size". Actually, this is a restriction to `Tile Push Notifications` size or external tile updated by a scheduler. From `Background Agent` you don't need to think about tile size

Comment: Sorry @Ku6opr but you are incorrect on your last item.  I had a major issue with images being greater than 85K.  They  just wouldn't show up.

Comment: I made changes to reflect correct pixel size and about internally generating images.  Thanks @Ku6opr for the additions!

Comment: Forgot to say that `Url` for tile must be written as `BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/...` to get an access to saved image

Comment: So, you could potentially download the images, then cache them in `/Shared/ShellContent`... interesting concept.